# Firefox new tab not displaying all tiles

Tags: windows-7, firefox

Normally tiles are displayed on a 3 x 5 grid but since few days the new tab windows don't show all tiles. I have 2 lines of 6 and the last line is totally hidden. I tried to update Firefox but it didn't fix this bug.

Any idea how to fix that problem without installing an add-on please ?

[image]

Comment: Goto `about:config` and look for `browser.newtabpage.columns` and `browser.newtabpage.rows`

Comment: `browser.newtabpage.columns` = 5 and `browser.newtabpage.rows` = 3.

Comment: Try and change `browser.newtab.preload` to `false` and also have a look at your zoom level in a new tab.

Comment: Any change and the screen show zoom 0. Zooming out let me see all tiles